# XlsxlWriter will only write one line in spreadsheet

Tags: python

Good Afternoon Everyone

I am writing a python script that will read a file of IP address and then ask for a prefix and then create an excel spread sheet with the prefix_IP address, IP address, Host or Network.

I been trying to figure out the problem for three hours now. It will only write on line in the spreadsheet even though there is 4 lines in the file and if I print the variable two it show 4

Here is the code and the sample file of IP

This script will import a csv file and then prompte for firewall address name prefix and export to spread sheet.

```
# These two command import the different library's we are using.
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/")
import os
import time
import csv
import re
import xlsxwriter



#Define the Functions
def main():

    userinput()


def userinput():
        address_file = input('Please enter name of file that contacts address and subnet mask:')
        address_prefix = input('Please enter address prefix for the new address')







        writefile(address_file, address_prefix)
        quit()
        return

def writefile(address_file,address_prefix):
    with open("%s.csv" % address_file) as csvfile:
        ip_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        row = 0
        col = 0
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        for line in ip_data:

            e_data = ','.join(line)
            end = ""

            if re.search("32$", e_data):
                end = "Host"
            else:
                end = "Network"

            print(address_prefix + e_data, e_data, end)

            worksheet.write(row, col, address_prefix + e_data)
            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, e_data)
            worksheet.write(row, col + 3, end)
            row += 1
            print(row)
            workbook.close()





    return




Sample file of address csv file 
10.10.10.1/32
2.2.2.0/24
3.3.3.3/32
5.5.5.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

The workbook.close() call is being done for each 'line', it should only be done after the for has completed. It's an indentation issue, move it one level to the left.